# Tikz graph labels: Error compiling example from manual

Tags: labels, tikz-graphs

I am trying to add labels to arrows in a Tikz graph. The following example from the manual, p. 260, does not compile on my updated TeXLive 2017 system. Both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` give this error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgf@temp.
<to be read again> 
                   2
l.15 }
      ;
```

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs} 
\begin{document} 
% from texdoc tikz, p. 260
\tikz
    \graph [edge quotes={fill=white,inner sep=1pt},
            grow down, branch right, nodes={circle,draw}] {
    "" -> h [>"9"] -> {
        c [>"4"] -> {
            a [>"2"], e [>"0"]
        }, j [>"7"]
    }
}; 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Ti*k*Z manual is great except it is not always clear which libraries you need to load. Here it is `quotes` which was missing.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes} 
\begin{document} 
% from texdoc tikz, p. 260
\tikz{
\graph [edge quotes={fill=white,inner sep=1pt},
grow down, branch right, nodes={circle,draw}] { "" -> h [>"9"] -> {
      c [>"4"] -> {
        a [>"2"],
        e [>"0"]
},
j [>"7"] 
}
} 
}
\end{document}
```